# How to hide Sidebar and show List as default?

Tags: trello

I'd like to use Trello as an ePortfolio for my high school students.  At school going through the process of hiding the Sidebar and showing the List is simple.

But, when my students eventually email ePortfolios links to potential employers and colleges...it would be much more user friendly for the recipient to navigate if the Sidebar was shown on default rather than the List.

Is this a possibility?

Comment: This is not possible currently. Sorry. Please feel free to email this request to feature-ideas@trello.com. Also, see http://trello.com/help for other resources.

Comment: @RichArmstrong this is a possible answer. Another possible answer is a hack via a userscript. There seems to be confusion as to when to reply with an answer that redirects a user to feature requests. Many of the other apps (like Facebook) have questions that are similar. As long as the user is not explicitly asking for a feature request (in which case the question can be easily so it is on-topic) it is okay here. Hope that clears things up. Feel free to ping me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu if you want more clarification.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "if the Sidebar was shown on default rather than the List." Can you provide a screen shot?